# jmeter: extract information from headers and save it to a variable

Tags: jmeter

My task is to make a request and save some data from the headers in a variable and use it later in another requests.

So I've added an http request and added an regular expression extractor. Here is my setup:
[image]

And then I've created another request and I'm using the `LocationToken` variable, but there the variable has the default value (dd). here is the response:

[image]

So, as you can see, the pattern patches on the headers. So what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Regular Expression Extractor`, under `Apply to` section, you should select `Main sampler and sub-samplers` option but not `JMeter Variable`.

`Regular Expression Extractor` saves the value into the variable which we specified in `Reference Name` field.

in the question,

```
Reference Name: LocationToken
```

in later request, you refer the value as follows:

```
${LocationToken}
```